# Como mostrar elementos em sequência?

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando mostrar os elementos em sequência:

```html
<p class="desc">1)INFORMACAO1?</p>
<p class="desc">2) INFORMACAO2</p>
<p class="desc">3)INFORMACAO3</p>
<p class="desc">4) INFORMACAO4</p>
<p class="desc">5) INFORMACAO5</p>
```

Não estou conseguindo com essa linha de código:

```
$(this).next('.desc').fadeIn('slow');
```

Assim funciona, porém mostra todos:

```
$('.desc').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 5):

Basta isolar em um método somente para fazer a exibição e adicionar um delay entre as chamadas.

```js
var tempoDeEspera = 1000; //milisegundos

$(".desc").each(function() {
  var elemento = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    exibirElemento(elemento);
  }, tempoDeEspera)
  tempoDeEspera += 1000;
});

function exibirElemento(elemento) {
  $(elemento).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

```css
.desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="desc">1)INFORMACAO1?</p>
<p class="desc">2) INFORMACAO2</p>
<p class="desc">3)INFORMACAO3</p>
<p class="desc">4) INFORMACAO4</p>
<p class="desc">5) INFORMACAO5</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar o método [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) do objeto jQuery para atrasar a execução da operação seguinte, no caso o `fadeIn`:

```js
// aumente ou diminua este valor para alterar o intervalo entre as animações.
var interval = 1000;

$('.desc').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i * (interval / 2)).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

```css
.desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="desc">1)INFORMACAO1?</p>
<p class="desc">2) INFORMACAO2</p>
<p class="desc">3)INFORMACAO3</p>
<p class="desc">4) INFORMACAO4</p>
<p class="desc">5) INFORMACAO5</p>
```

Comment: Também é um método de fazer... mas os intervalos não são fixos.. neste caso vai ser de `0,500,1000,1500,2000`. Mas olha...te respeitei só pelo seu "nick"... melhor banda do planeta. `+1`

Comment: @MarllonNasser na verdade são fixos. O intervalo entre as animações sempre vai ser `interval / 2`. No exemplo o intervalo vai ser sempre de 500 milissegundos. Sei que o espaço não é pra off-topic, mas tenho que concordar. Tá pra nascer uma banda melhor que essa. \,,/

Comment: O "i" é incrementado, certo? Então na primeira interação é `0*(1000/2)=0`. 
Na segunda interação é `1*(1000/2)=500`. Na terceira `2*(1000/2)=1000`. E assim por diante... mas é uma solução também! Como você falou não tem nada na pergunta solicitando que o intervalo seja fixo... por isso dei `+1`. \m/

Comment: @MarllonNasser vale notar aqui é que o `delay` não atrasa a execução do `each`. Isso quer dizer que os delays são praticamente concorrentes, então podemos prever o intervalo entre o início de uma animação para o início de outra com: `intervalo atual - intervalo anterior`. Logo quando a segunda animação começar terão se passado  `500 - 0` milissegundos desde o início da primeira. Da terceira animação para segunda: `1000 - 500`. Quarta para Terceira: `1500 - 1000`...  isso se aplica também na sua resposta, que tem o intervalo fixo de `1000`, já que o `setTimeout` não atrasa a execução do `each`.